# How to delete everything after the second " " in a string, using the replace(), slice() or other function in google sheets

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

So I am currently developing a function to format some input cells on Google Sheets using the app scripts api.

Right now I am taking input from a few cells and formatting them slightly to conform to a manually generated system.

One cell is a school name cell. Sometimes these names tend to be long, I am not super experienced in javascript but right now I am taking an argument from a cell, how would I define that argument's variable so that it would only accept everything in the cell up to the second space.

**EX:**
Cell A#: Fill-in-the-blank High School Union

**Output:** Fill-in-the-blank High

```
/**
*Generates a Trip Key
*
*@param DateColumn Date 
*@param SchoolColumn School name
*@param LocationColumn Location
*@customfunction
*/
function GENERATEKEY(DateColumn, SchoolColumn, LocationColumn) {
  var DateConver = Utilities.formatDate(DateColumn, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM.dd.yyyy");
  var SchoolClean = SchoolColumn.replace(

  return DateConver + " " + SchoolColumn + " " + "@" + " " +  LocationColumn  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to match everything up to the second space.

```
var SchoolClean = SchoolColumn.replace(/^(\S*\s*\S*).*/, '$1');
```

`\S` matches non-whitespace characters, `\s` matches whitespace. So `\S*\s*\S*` matches non-spaces followed by spaces followed by non-spaces. Then `.*` matches the rest of the string. The replacement is `$1`, which is just what was matched by the part inside parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectText(data) {
  var idx1=data.indexOf(' ');//location of first space
  var idx2=data.indexOf(' ',idx1+1);//starts looking for second space 1 after first space.
  var s=data.slice(0,idx2);//idx2 + 1 if you want the second space
  return s;
}
```